# tkinter not displaying images on forms

Tags: python, forms, image, file, tkinter

I cannot for the life in me work out why this does not work. I am using TKinter to display an image in Python. The code I have written so far is shown here:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def unlock():
    root.withdraw()


    def logout():
        inside.destroy()
        root.deiconify()

    #######################
    ###                 ###
    ###  unlock Form    ###
    ###                 ###
    #######################


    inside = Tk()
    inside.geometry("576x576")
    inside.title("SAFE CRACKER")
    # LABELS, Textboxes and Buttons
    imageInside = PhotoImage(file = "images/inside.gif")
    imageLabel = Label(inside,image = imageInside).grid(row =1, columnspan = 2)
    label = Label(inside, text="Safe Cracker", font = ("Arial",16)).grid(row = 0, columnspan = 2)
    exitButton = Button(inside, text = "Exit", width = 15, command = logout )
    exitButton.grid(row = 3, column = 0,padx = 10, pady = 10)



#######################
###                 ###
###    Main Form    ###
###                 ###
#######################


root = Tk()
root.geometry("430x450")
root.title("SAFE CRACKER")
# LABELS, Textboxes and Buttons
label = Label(root, text="Safe Cracker", font = ("Arial",16)).grid(row = 0, columnspan = 2)
imageSafe = PhotoImage(file = "images/safe.gif")
imageLabel = Label(root,image = imageSafe).grid(row =1, columnspan = 2)
label = Label(root, text = "Enter the code", font = ("Arial",12)).grid(row  = 2, column = 0)
unlockCode = Entry(root, width = 30)
unlockCode.grid(row = 2, column = 1,padx = 10, pady = 10)
exitButton = Button(root, text = "Exit", width = 15, command = exit).grid(row = 3, column = 0,padx = 10, pady = 10)
enterButton = Button(root, text = "Enter the VAULT", width = 15, command = unlock).grid(row = 3, column = 1,padx = 10, pady = 10)
```

The code doesn't do much at present, however it's something i'm working on. When I run the program it will display a picture of a safe (Great), and when I click the button it moves over to the next form.

[image of safe working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TZp6.png)

On the new form the image, labels and buttons do not display, however, when the image code is removed it all works swimmingly.

Initially I thought about putting the root form within a function, however, whenever I place this code within a function it fails to load the image (ahhhh). Can these images not be placed within functions?

Comment: maybe you get errror and it can't display form. Did you run it in console to see if you get error message?

Comment: BTW: when you do `var = Widget(...).grid()` then it assigns `None` to `var` because `grid()` (and `pack()`) returns `None`, not widget. If you need `var` to access widget later then you have to do it in two lines of code ` `var = Widget(...)` and `var.grid()`. If you don't need to use `var` later then you can create widget without `var`. It means  `Widget(...).grid()`

Comment: `tkinter` should use only one `Tk()` - to create main window. Other windows you should create with `Toplevel()`

Comment: BTW: you forgot `root.mainloop()`

Comment: @furas i'm not sure what you mean? A lot of this is self taught, therefore i've probably picked up a lot of bad habits. How would you create a new window?

Comment: main window you create with `root = Tk()` and you add widgets ie. `Label(root)` , second window (subwindow, dialog) you create with `inside = Toplevel()` and you add widgets ie. `Label(inside)`. So the difference is that you use `Toplevel` instead `Tk` to create second window.

Comment: @furas For additional windows, would you still use Toplevel()?

Comment: yes - you should use `Tk()` only to create main window - "unlock Form" (as second window) should use `inside = Toplevel()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the photo.

```
imageInside = PhotoImage(file = "images/inside.gif")
imageLabel = Label(inside,image = imageInside)
imageLabel.grid(row =1, columnspan = 2)
imageLabel.photo_ref = imageInside # keep a reference!
```

Comment: Than you for the help but that didn't work. It came back with this:
    imageLabel = Label(inside,image = imageInside)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2760, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2293, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist

Comment: @NeosNokia You should rather edit that to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help.

I can confirm that this works, here's the code.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def unlock():
    root.withdraw()


    def logout():
        inside.destroy()
        root.deiconify()

    #######################
    ###                 ###
    ###  unlock Form    ###
    ###                 ###
    #######################


    inside = Toplevel()
    inside.geometry("576x576")
    inside.title("SAFE CRACKER")
    # LABELS, Textboxes and Buttons
    imageInside = PhotoImage(file = "images/inside.gif")
    imageLabel = Label(inside,image = imageInside)
    imageLabel.grid(row =1, columnspan = 2)
    imageLabel.photo_ref = imageInside
    label = Label(inside, text="Safe Cracker", font = ("Arial",16)).grid(row = 0, columnspan = 2)
    exitButton = Button(inside, text = "Exit", width = 15, command = logout )
    exitButton.grid(row = 3, column = 0,padx = 10, pady = 10)



#######################
###                 ###
###    Main Form    ###
###                 ###
#######################


root = Tk()
root.geometry("430x450")
root.title("SAFE CRACKER")
# LABELS, Textboxes and Buttons
label = Label(root, text="Safe Cracker", font = ("Arial",16)).grid(row = 0, columnspan = 2)
imageSafe = PhotoImage(file = "images/safe.gif")
imageLabel = Label(root,image = imageSafe).grid(row =1, columnspan = 2)
label = Label(root, text = "Enter the code", font = ("Arial",12)).grid(row  = 2, column = 0)
unlockCode = Entry(root, width = 30)
unlockCode.grid(row = 2, column = 1,padx = 10, pady = 10)
exitButton = Button(root, text = "Exit", width = 15, command = exit).grid(row = 3, column = 0,padx = 10, pady = 10)
enterButton = Button(root, text = "Enter the VAULT", width = 15, command = unlock).grid(row = 3, column = 1,padx = 10, pady = 10)
```